# Getting a NullPointerException when clearly my array has data in it

Tags: java, arrays, exception, nullpointerexception, null

I am trying to make my own version of a credit card validator and currently I am in the process of checking the digits using Luhn's algorithm. In this code snippet I am moving the credit card digits in and out of arrays and changing them from ints to strings and vice versa. 
Here is my code snippet:

```
  public static void checkDigits(){
  System.out.println("Printing out charat card:");
   //check digits
  checkDigits = new int[length];
  for(int i = 0; i < length ; i++){
     checkDigits[i] = Integer.parseInt(card.substring(i,i+1));

  //successfully puts digits into array
  }
  for(int e = length-2; e >= 0; e-=2){
     checkDigits[e] = 2*checkDigits[e];
  }
  for(int d = 0; d < length; d++){
     holdDigitsChar.add(String.valueOf(checkDigits[d])); 
  }
  for(int v = 0; v<length;v++){
     if(holdDigitsChar.get(v).length() == 2){
        holdDigits.add(Integer.parseInt(holdDigitsChar.get(v).substring(0,1)));
        holdDigits.add(Integer.parseInt(holdDigitsChar.get(v).substring(1,2)));
     }
     else{
        holdDigits.add(Integer.parseInt(holdDigitsChar.get(v)));
     }
  }
  for(int c = 0; c < holdDigits.size(); c++){
     checkSum += holdDigits.get(c);
  }
  System.out.println("Check sum:" +checkSum);
 }
```

It is saying there is a NPE on the line:

```
  holdDigitsChar.add(String.valueOf(checkDigits[d]));
```

I have checked the array with print statements and it is returning the string of numbers from the credit card. Why is it giving me a null pointer? I can paste the rest of my code if that is helpful.

Thanks.

PS I have not gotten past this line so I am not sure if the other part works either.

Comment: the NPE means that holdDigitsChar is null, not checkDigits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: `holdDigitsChar` is null. Try searching harder next time.

Comment: Thanks, I tend to get the hard parts of programming down, but always miss the tiny little things.